# How to get number of records along with min/max values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, max, min, record-count

I have a search form (running `MySQL 5.0.88`) to drill down through a product table. The search is a 2-step search. First run gets the `number of results`, 2nd run gets the `data of records x-y`.

I'm displaying min/max prices across all records by default and now want to update the min/max values based on the query results. I was thinking the best way to do this is inside the inital query, that gets the number of records.

Currently it looks like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT( a.id ) AS recordcount
        , a.nos
        , a.nos_anzeige

FROM artikelstammdaten a

WHERE 
        a.iln != "1111111111111" AND a.iln != "2222222222222" AND a.iln != "7777777777777"
    AND a.aktiv = "ja"
    AND a.artikelnummer LIKE '%name%' 
AND (a.modus = "OPEN" 
        OR a.iln IN ( 55555555555,66666666666,2222222222222 ) 
        )

GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer, a.preis_aktuell, a.artikelbezeichnung
HAVING (( sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.anzeige  = "ja" ))
```

Which gives me all matching records.

**Problem**:
Actually I only want the number of records (~ `query.recordcount` ) in a single record and not the individual records one by one (my attempt with `COUNT` doesn't work). Something like this:

```
  totalrecords    min-price   max-price
  12345           9.99        1.204
```

where I can try to select min/max values across the resultset.

**Question**:
How do I have to modify my query, so I'm only getting the totalrecords (and can try to add min/max values)?

THANKS!

** EDIT: **
My table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE dummy (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`iln` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ean` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`artikelnummer` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`preis_ek` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`preis_vk` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`firma` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nos` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`nos_anzeige` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`aktiv` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`modus` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`bestand` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT '0'
 )
```

Prices would be `preis_ek` and `preis_vk` where I'm looking for min/max for each. THANKS!

**EDIT**: 
Running the query like it is gives me a resultset like this:

```
"id"    "nos"   "nos_anzeige"   "MIN(a.preis_ek)"
"1153837"   "nein"  "nein"  "25,10"
"1153797"   "nein"  "nein"  "12,40"
....
```

which picks the `min` per record not across the resultset, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: what is the structure of the table,where is price column in the table?

Comment: there are min and max functions that you can use in your query eg.
`SELECT max(id) FROM table`

Comment: but the query like it is gives me every matching records separately vs. a single record with the recordcount.

Comment: @frequent: Of course it is, you are using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Travesty3 - so I can't have a single record and group by?

Comment: @frequent you are using group by clause just for `(( sum(a.bestand) != 0 )`, am i right? then you can make it a temp table and obtain count on that, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
    SELECT count(recordcount), 
       Max(max_price), 
       Min(min_price) 
       FROM   (SELECT Count(a.id)   AS recordcount, 
               a.nos, 
               a.nos_anzeige, 
               Max(preis_ek) AS max_price, 
               Min(preis_ek) AS min_price 
        FROM   artikelstammdaten a 
        WHERE  a.iln != "1111111111111" 
               AND a.iln != "2222222222222" 
               AND a.iln != "7777777777777" 
               AND a.aktiv = "ja" 
               AND a.artikelnummer LIKE '%name%' 
               AND ( a.modus = "open" 
                      OR a.iln IN ( 55555555555, 66666666666, 2222222222222 ) ) 
        GROUP  BY a.iln, 
                  a.artikelnummer, 
                  a.preis_aktuell, 
                  a.artikelbezeichnung 
        HAVING ( ( Sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) 
                  OR ( a.nos = "ja" 
                       AND a.anzeige = "ja" ) )) temp
```

Comment: right track. how to fix `every derived table must have it's own table name`?

Comment: One thing: Change the beginning to: `Count(recordcount), max(max_price), min(min_price) from (SELECT  a.id AS recordcount...` Otherwise I'm COUNTing the SUM of matching ids, so style 123 with size s,m,l,xl would be 4 ids, which should be counted as 1 and not 4... hope that was clear

Comment: but aren't you already using `Count(a.id)   AS recordcount` in your inner query, if you want to consider each row as one record then your suggestion is correct, will make the change:)